# Show value as percentage in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data -

| E no | e name | met with MD as |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55467 | ALFRED | CLS |
| 324 | ROBERT | CCSG |
| 9876 | SOVIYY | as lady employee |
| 536 | CREFY | CLS |
| 789 | LOYED | OSDS |
| 86 | ZIKO.M | CCF |

**and I was asked to show the % of employees who have met MD** and show them in card visualisation powerBI. I am new to power BI and I have to complete this project for my final year and I got stuck.
Please help me in completing this. Please share if u have any code in DAX to perform.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Which value indicates an employee met with the MD or not?

Comment: E_name and E code  are the employee details of name and code, met with MD is the column which we have to consider I think. I have the data in the same manner, it's confusing a bit

Comment: met with MD as is the column, fine. But which value in that column indicates the employee met with the MD?

Comment: Sir, I (last name ROY)have sent you a request in linked in please accept it.,

Comment: Better you add your expected output from the above sample data.

Comment: @mkRabbani thanks for your reply, will get back if I face any difficulty again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited input dataset which you have
Are there any blank values in the met with MD as column for any employee?
If yes, then the task would be

Distinct count of employees where Met with MD column<>''

You can use the below DAX functions to achieve it:

1. Calculate, count or distinctcount , filter and finally Divide for %

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will try do it for sure...thanks again